# CMake: Fail to install symlink on ssh-mounted filesystem

Tags: linux, cmake, cross-compiling, symlink, sshfs

I am cross-compiling a project on my desktop, and installing it on a device which is mounted via ssh, using sshfs, like so:

```
    sudo sshfs -o allow_other -o follow_symlinks user@192.168.12.100:/ /mnt/remote
```

The build is successful, but when I try to "sudo make install", I receive the following message:

```
    -- Installing: /mnt/remote/usr/lib/libprop.so.5.1.5
    -- Installing: /mnt/remote/usr/lib/libprop.so.5
    CMake Error: failed to create symbolic link '/mnt/remote/usr/lib/libprop.so.5': i/o error
    CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:176 (file):file INSTALL cannot duplicate symlink
      "/home/ubuntu/libprop/build/lib/libprop.so.5" at
      "/mnt/remote/usr/lib/libprop.so.5".
```

The library and the symlink are copied and created. That is, it seems that the installation actually succeeds, but CMake thinks otherwise.
The filesystem is not ro, as can be seen in `mount` output:

```
    user@192.168.12.100:/ on /mnt/remote type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
```

And I can see the entry under /mnt/ (I chown'd and chmod'd it for user access, thinking it might solve the problem):

```
    drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 11 13:43 remote
```

and I can access it event without root permissions, copying and deleting files without a problem.
This process has been working for me. I have no idea what was changed that it stopped. Could be something in my environment or maybe in the destination platform.

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the problem... I shouldn't be using `-o follow_symlinks`. I guess this can cause other problems (I used it for a reason), but for the purpose of compiling and installing, it works.